# grails 2.3 events push plugin

Tags: events, grails, plugins, push-notification

Using grails 2.3.0 and groovy 2.1.6 and following the setup in:
https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push/blob/master/README.md

I get in firebug:

```
Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending {"topic":"saveTodo","body":"data"}
jquery...here.js (line 2436)
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/pushEvents/g-eventsbus/eventsbus?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=1.1.0.beta3&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&topics=eventsbus.

if (jQuery.browser.msie) {

jquery...here.js (line 1276)
TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined

if (jQuery.browser.msie) {

jquery...here.js (line 1276)
The connection to ws://localhost:8080/pushEvents/g-eventsbus/eventsbus?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=1.1.0.beta3&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&topics=eventsbus was interrupted while the page was loading.

return new WebSocket(location);
```

Nothing seems to happen.

**Is events push working with this grails version?**

Answer (score 0):

No it does not. https://bitbucket.org/bgoetzmann/grails-atmosphere-plugin/issue/11/plugin-doesnt-work-with-jquery-core-19 .

Because it's based on atmosphere. 
And I don't think that is the only issue. There might be server issues also.

Comment: http://grails.org/plugin/atmosphere plugin works well with grails. Make sure you are configuring & making proper connections using client and server side code